# How do I make a PayPal donate button default to an amount?

Tags: paypal

How do I make a PayPal donate button default to $10 but enable users to change the amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this tutorial](https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppintegrationsnate/create-paypal-pay-now-button-amount-input) I made a textbox where the user is able to specify the amount they want to pay on a form I have complete control over, before I send them to a PayPal webpage to complete the transaction.

My gemfile:

```
gem 'paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments'
```

My Ruby payment code

```
  p = PayPalPayer.new
  amt = @buyamount.to_f
  trackingId = SecureRandom.uuid
  senderEmail = 'senderemail@emailaddress.com'
  receiverEmail = 'receiveremail@emailaddress.com'
  url = 'http://redirectotohereafterpaymentcomplets'
  pay = p.pay(senderEmail, receiverEmail, amt, url, trackingId)
  redirect pay[:url] //this takes the user to a page to complete the payment
```

Comment: That link is broken :-(

Comment: Today I learned why it is against policy to just post links. I dug up my code and pasted it in.

Comment: Much appreciated!